# Trying to scrape to a csv file

Tags: r, sharepoint, rvest, rselenium

I am trying to scrape with R the data from this site:

http://relatorios.aneel.gov.br/_layouts/xlviewer.aspx?id=/RelatoriosSAS/RelSAMPClasseConsNivel.xlsx&Source=http%3A%2F%2Frelatorios%2Eaneel%2Egov%2Ebr%2FRelatoriosSAS%2FForms%2FAllItems%2Easpx&DefaultItemOpen=1

It's a sharepoint database..

I've tried RSelenium pakckage:

```
    rD <- rsDriver(verbose = FALSE,port=4000L,chromever = "86.0.4240.22")
    
    remDr <- rD$client
    
    remDr$navigate("http://relatorios.aneel.gov.br/_layouts/xlviewer.aspx?id=/RelatoriosSAS/RelSAMPClasseConsNivel.xlsx&Source=http%3A%2F%2Frelatorios%2Eaneel%2Egov%2Ebr%2FRelatoriosSAS%2FForms%2FAllItems%2Easpx&DefaultItemOpen=1") 
    
        webElem <- remDr$findElement(using = "xpath", value = "//*[@id='ctl00_PlaceHolderMain_m_excelWebRenderer_ewaCtl_clientAreaDiv']")

a <- webElem$getElementText()
```

but it doesn't bring all data. And I tried with rvest also, but no sucess..

Any suggestions?

Thanks!

updated:

```
b <- webElem$getPageSource()
c <- readHTMLTable(b[[1]],header = T,as.data.frame = T)
View(c[[5]])
```

almost, but still missing some results

Comment: I'm not able to open the URL. 
Is it working for you?

Comment: Yes, but the site have a limit access per hour I think. Anyways, I did the scrap and share the code on my github: https://github.com/brunocristiano/AuditandoTudo/blob/main/scrap.R